# Net user command does not show all users

Tags: command-prompt

I'm creating a batch file for my day-to-day use in my company. I need on a Win7 and Win10 computer, to retrieve the actual username the computer is assigned to. 
Therefore I have 02 situations:
1) If user is present, I have him logged in then I use "Run as administrator" to launch my batch file that contains following command:

query user /server:%computername%'

In that case I have no issue and the user name will will populate as he is logged in (Note that environment variable %USERNAME% only shows my admin account).

2) If user is away, I need to log in with my admin account, run a command (NET USERS) that will list all users having a local or logon account and chose the correct one.

In the second case (This is where I'm stuck). I'm using my own system as a test to build my batch file and I noticed can't get both my own account and my admin account listed.

[image]